# Display images from sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

I'm trying to print a list of movies from the Films table of a database that has the fields (IdFilm, Poster, Title, Country, Gender). All fields are printed correctly except the poster field.

I do not know exactly what datatype I should save the images in the database (image or varbinary(max)). I have saved them as varchar with the name of the image for example (photo1.jpg) and I have tried to display the images in this way, but it does not work:

Clase show:

```
package entity;

import dao.dbmanager;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class show {
    private final String URL = "images/";

    private int id;
    private String photo;
    private String title;
    private String country;
    private String gender;

    public show(int id, String photo, String title, String country, String gender) {
        this.id = id;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.title = title;
        this.country = country;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public show() {
    }

    public static Vector ShowData() {
        Vector film = null;
        try {
            dbmanager db = new dbmanager();
            Connection con = db.Connect();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from Films");
            film = new Vector();

            while(rs.next()) 
                film.add(new show(rs.getInt("idFilm"), rs.getString("poster"), rs.getString("title"), rs.getString("country"), rs.getString("gender")));
                return film;
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photoName) {
        this.photo = URL + photoName;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Vector"%>
<%@page import="entity.show"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="f1" method="POST">
            <center>
        <table border="1">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Poster</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td>Gender</td>
            </tr>
            <%
                show objfilm = new show();
                Vector film = new Vector();
                film = objfilm.ShowData();

                for(int i=0; i < film.size(); i++) {
                    objfilm = (show)film.get(i);
            %>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><%=objfilm.getId() %></td>
                <td><img src="<%=objfilm.getPhoto() %>"></td>
                <td><%=objfilm.getTitle() %></td>
                <td><%=objfilm.getCountry() %></td>
                <td><%=objfilm.getGender() %></td> 
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </table>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how to display the images (poster) for each record.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you store the images?

Comment: Like base64 or saved to physical location and saves the related path in db?

Comment: If you store binary images in SQL Server, you should use varbinary(MAX) for the SQL data type. The image data type has been deprecated for many years.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the images on disk (preferable in a folder outside the webserver). Rename the images to a unique name (hash) upon saving and store this hash (plus original name) in a table as a varchar type.

To show the image just refer to that logical path that maps to the folder of your posters.
In Tomcat it is something like

```
<Context path="/posters" docBase="C:/data/posters" debug="0" privileged="true"></Context>
```

Now you can show the post like

```
<img src="/posters/<%= objfilm.hashName %>" alt="<%= objfilm.origName %>" />
```